# standalone repo for upgrading

Tags: upgrade, repository, wget

I am new to ubuntu

I have an ubuntu 14.04 system on an isolated network (no access to internet) that I need to upgrade.  I would like to pull a copy of a repo to use on this isolated network.  I would be using windows or Centos connected to the internet to download the repo.

Can I use wget --recursive to do this?  For example:
wget --recursive http://path/to/ubuntu16/dists/xenial
wget --recursive http://path/to/ubuntu16/dists/xenial-updates
wget --recursive http://path/to/ubuntu16/dists/xenial-security

Is this sufficient for doing the upgrade?

TIA

Comment: Try looking at https://superuser.com/q/876727/368145 which would probably do what you need.

Comment: or potentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674495/3763363